# Where can I find "Outlook 2016 Add-in" for Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, outlook, ms-office

I want to specifically create a VSTO for Outlook 2016 Desktop application but my Visual Studio 2013 Professional edition only has "Outlook 2013 Add-in" and the "App for Office" creates a Web App.

Where can I find this installer/option?

Comment: An outlook 2013 add-in will work in Outlook 2016, so long as it doesn't need features that are new in 2016.

Comment: Hi Erik, Is there a way to specifically get the 2016 project so that I can make use of any Outlook 2016 features?

Answer (score 1):

See [Walkthrough: Creating Your First VSTO Add-In for Outlook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668191.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). You need to choose the Outlook 2013 Add-in template in Visual Studio. Then you can replace the Outlook PIA with a new one which corresponds to Outlook 2016.

You may find the [Running Solutions in Different Versions of Microsoft Office](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb772080.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) article helpful.

P.S. Try to install http://aka.ms/officedevtoolsforvs2015

Answer (score 1):

If you have Office 2016 installed then you should have the Office 16.0 Object library in your COM references in Visual Studio.

I had this issue with the 2016 template option not showing and a build error of `Cannot debug project because required version of MS Office application is not installed` when I tried picking 2013.

Once I enabled the 16.0 Object Library the PIA (Primary Interop Assemblies) were added and after restarting Visual Studio the Outlook template option shows Outlook 2013 and 2016 VSTO Add-in

[image: Visual Studio COM references]